# RewriteCond validates always to false

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a regular expression in my RewriteRule, which is currently working fine. Secondly I'd like to test wheter the file (where the request is rewritten at) exists. Therefore I placed a RewriteCond before my rule, but it validates always to false, unfortunately.

This is my regex:

```
assets/img(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]*)\.([^/]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})
```

And I created this .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond assets/img$1/.$2.$4/$3.$4 -s
RewriteRule ^assets/img(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]*)\.([^/]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ assets/img$1/.$2.$4/$3.$4 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^assets/img(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]*)\.([^/]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ assets/img/image.php?path=$1&file=$2.$4&key=$3&ext=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
```

A request without the RewriteCond, where the rewritten location exists, is working normally. For those who're interested, my complete .htaccess is posted here: http://pastie.org/1293667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `RewriteCond` only applies to the rule immediately following it, so your second `RewriteRule` is always run.  One solution [is to negate the test you are making, then have the next command skip the two commands you want to run](http://my.galagzee.com/2009/02/11/mod_rewrite-one-rewritecond-to-many-rewriterules/).

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}assets/img$1/.$2.$4/$3.$4 !-f
RewriteRule . - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^assets/img(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]*)\.([^/]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ assets/img$1/.$2.$4/$3.$4 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^assets/img(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]*)\.([^/]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ assets/img/image.php?path=$1&file=$2.$4&key=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Adding a skip flag (skipping 1 rule) to Jurian's first RewriteRule should be sufficient, assuming I understand his intent correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is really helpful! Unfortunately I notice now the first rule (rewriting to another location of the image) does not work at all (eg when the condition and second rule are removed). Still, a direct request (see question) works fine. There is more wrong than just the skip flag?

Comment: Ok, I found out why your rules didn't work. I used mod_vhost_alias and therefore DOCUMENT_ROOT is not changed to the right value. There is a bug filed about this: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26052. Anyhow, your answer was in the end the right one.